# Filtering Products by Price is not working MERN Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Hi I am building an Ecommerce Application using MERN Stack with redux. But having issues when i try to send price array arguement in my fetching function. It is giving me the error that XHR GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products?keyword=&page=1&price[gt]=undefined&price[lt]=undefined
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 12ms]. Here is my Products.jsx Component Code {success:false,message:'Resource not found invalid Price'}

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Slider, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';
import { clearErrors, getProducts } from '../../actions/productActions';
import Loader from '../layout/Loader/Loader';
import ProductCard from '../Home/ProductCard';
import './Products.css';
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination';

const Products = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const alert = useAlert();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0, 25000);

  const { loading, products, productsCount, error, resultPerPage} =
    useSelector((state) => state.products);

  const keyword = match.params.keyword;

  const setCurrentPageNo = (e) => {
    setCurrentPage(e);
  };

  const priceHandler = (e, newPrice) => {
    setPrice(newPrice);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }

    dispatch(getProducts(keyword, currentPage, price));
  }, [dispatch, keyword, currentPage]);

  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2 className='productsHeading'>Products</h2>

          <div className='products'>
            {products &&
              products.map((product) => (
                <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </div>

          <div className='filterBox'>
            <Typography>Price</Typography>
            <Slider
              value={price}
              onChange={priceHandler}
              valueLabelDisplay='auto'
              aria-labelledby='range-slider'
              min={0}
              max={25000}
            />
          </div>
          {resultPerPage < productsCount && (
            <div className='paginationBox'>
              <Pagination
                activePage={currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={resultPerPage}
                totalItemsCount={productsCount}
                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                nextPageText='Next'
                prevPageText='Prev'
                firstPageText='1st'
                lastPageText='Last'
                itemClass='page-item'
                linkClass='page-link'
                activeClass='pageItemActive'
                activeLinkClass='pageLinkActive'
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

And here is my action for getting allproducts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export const getProducts =
  (keyword = '', currentPage = 1, price = [0, 25000]) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
      });
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gt]=${price[0]}&price[lt]=${price[1]}`
      );

      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

Here is the Reducer for Products

```
export const productReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        products: [],
      };

    case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload.products,
        productsCount: action.payload.productsCount,
        resultPerPage: action.payload.resultPerPage,
      };
    case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am Using Custom Error Handling Class and here is the code for this

```
class ErrorResponse extends Error {
  constructor(message, statusCode) {
    super(message);
    this.statusCode = statusCode;

    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}

module.exports = ErrorResponse;
```

And here is the middleware function

```
const ErrorResponse = require('../utils/errorResponse');

const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';

  // Wrong Mongodb Id error
  if (err.name === 'CastError') {
    const message = `Resource not found. Invalid: ${err.path}`;
    err = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
  }

  // Mongoose duplicate key error
  if (err.code === 11000) {
    const message = `Duplicate ${Object.keys(err.keyValue)} Entered`;
    err = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
  }

  // Wrong JWT error
  if (err.name === 'JsonWebTokenError') {
    const message = `Json Web Token is invalid, Try again `;
    err = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
  }

  // JWT EXPIRE error
  if (err.name === 'TokenExpiredError') {
    const message = `Json Web Token is Expired, Try again `;
    err = new ErrorResponse(message, 400);
  }

  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    success: false,
    message: err.message,
  });
};

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Here is my ApiFeatures class for filtering, Pagination and Sorting

```
class ApiFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryStr) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryStr = queryStr;
  }

  search() {
    const keyword = this.queryStr.keyword
      ? {
          name: {
            $regex: this.queryStr.keyword,
            $options: 'i',
          },
        }
      : {};

    this.query = this.query.find({ ...keyword });
    return this;
  }

  filter() {
    const queryCopy = { ...this.queryStr };

    //Removing fields
    const removFields = ['keyword', 'page', 'limit'];

    removFields.forEach((key) => delete queryCopy[key]);

    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryCopy);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gt|gte|lt|lte)\b/g, (key) => `$${key}`);

    this.query = this.query.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
    return this;
  }

  pagination(resultPerPage) {
    const currentPage = Number(this.queryStr.page) || 1;

    const skip = resultPerPage * (currentPage - 1);

    this.query = this.query.limit(resultPerPage).skip(skip);

    return this;
  }
}

module.exports = ApiFeatures;
```

Here is my controller function

```
const getProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const resultPerPage = 8;
  const productsCount = await Product.countDocuments();

  const apiFeatures = new ApiFeatures(Product.find(), req.query)
    .search()
    .filter()
    .pagination(resultPerPage);

  const products = await apiFeatures.query;

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    count: products.length,
    productsCount,
    resultPerPage,
    products,
  });
});
```

My Product Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter product Name'],
    trim: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter product Description'],
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter product Price'],
    maxLength: [8, 'Price cannot exceed 8 characters'],
  },
  ratings: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  images: [
    {
      public_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      url: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter Product Category'],
  },
  Stock: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Please Enter product Stock'],
    maxLength: [4, 'Stock cannot exceed 4 characters'],
    default: 1,
  },
  numOfReviews: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  reviews: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],

  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

I am not figuring it out that what is the issue coz i have tested this api on postman and it is giving correct results. Help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a first look, the url on which you're sending the request is `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products?keyword=&page=1&price[gt]=undefined&price[lt]=undefined`.

I feel the problem is generated by sending `undefined` values.

First, initialize price in your state to an array of 2 elements if you're accessing that way in the action.

```
const [price, setPrice] = useState([0, 25000]);
```

Second, make sure you are getting the right value from your filter

```
const priceHandler = (e, newPrice) => {
    console.log(newPrice) // Maybe the value you need isn't being passed in the call
    setPrice(newPrice);
};
```

Also, you can inspect the value of price coming in the action and see if it's really an array.

```
export const getProducts =
  (keyword = '', currentPage = 1, price = [0, 25000]) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    console.log(price) // and look at the value here
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
      });
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[gt]=${price[0]}&price[lt]=${price[1]}`
      );
  // Rest of the function ...
  };
```

Comment: That Works. I was accessing only single value in useState but i need to have array for slider. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it helped @Awais